# Fields/Data not visible in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, apache, mongodb, django-nonrel

I have used django-nonrel to connect Django and Mongodb, as the database.
When I deploy my app through apache on my machine, I can view the models/collections but cannot view the fields/data in the collections through Django Admin nor can I perform any mongodb operations through pymongo in the scripts/views (views.py) as they return no results.

However, when I run it locally using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

then I can view all my data in Django Admin panel and the pymongo operations also give the correct results.

I have registered the models and have also tried using `ALLOWED_HOSTS` as suggested in one of the posts

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', MY_IP]
```

The database is on a remote server(Amazon's server). Do I need to provide any other authentication to access the data when I deploy it on a server?

Comment: Does your production database actually have any data?

Comment: Yes, I haven't changed the settings to connect to the database and when I run it locally with the same settings, I can see the data in Django admin.